# Is it possible to return an img to <img src=""> without serving it as static?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

Right now I'm returning image from controller in C# with

> return File(bytes, "image/jpeg");

and it works fine, but it literally returns file. Meanwhile I'd want to return images that will be displayed *on the page* but without making them static (so, if user gives somebody else url, then he'll have to log in in order to be able to access them).

The only way to do it that I managed to find is Base64 encoding, and it works fine, but it seems to be a kind of laggy for browser when the img size is increasing.

Maybe that's some kind of injecting images into .cshtml but it sounds like `Base64`

Comment: Webservers are not driven by magic. Either you pay the higher initial load (with base64 embedded image) for lesser requests, use static files or return them dynamically from controller. You should always use static files when possible, cause you can use CDNs which increases load speed (browser can open more connections when static files are on different domain) and the static files domain can be cookie less, which reduces the overhead of sending cookie with each request

Comment: @Tseng ``Either you pay the higher initial load (with base64 embedded image) for lesser requests, use static files or return them dynamically from controller.`` base64, static files and what's the 3rd one? "return dynamically"? via javascript? Anyway. My goal is to serve images only to an authorized users (I'm verifying that in controller), so I'm curious whether it is possible

Comment: 1. base 64, 2. static files 3. dynamic from controllers (by streaming a file either from file system or database)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller you have an action like this (exactly as you described):

```
public class PhotoController : Controller {
    public ActionResult GetPhoto() {
        ...
        return File(bytes, "image/jpeg");
    }
}
```

If you're just pulling the file from the file system, you can do this (if the file is in your website folder):

```
return File("~/images/" + name, "image/jpeg");
```

Or if the file is outside of your website folder:

```
return PhysicalFile("C:\\images\\" + name, "image/jpeg");
```

Then in your page, you have an image that has a source pointing to that action:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetPhoto", "Photo")">
```

Comment: If you're pulling from a static file, you can just give it the path to the file, and it'll handle the rest: `return File(filename, "image/jpeg");`

Comment: ``var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\images\\" + name);
 return File(bytes, "image/jpeg");`` - Works fine, meanwhile ``return File("C:\\images\\" + name, "image/jpeg");`` doesnt. Exception: ``An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
FileNotFoundException: Could not find file: C:\images\1.jpg`` for some reason...

Comment: it requires creating a virtual directory, probably.

Comment: Oh, I see. `File()` requires a path relative to the wwwroot folder (e.g. `File("~/images/1.jpg")`. But if the path is outside of the website folder, you can use [`PhysicalFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.physicalfile?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_PhysicalFile_System_String_System_String_) (e.g. `return PhysicalFile("C:\\images\\" + name, "image/jpeg");`

Answer (score 1):

You create a separate "page" for the image that still just returns the image file. The page knows which image to show and whether to show based on the user and URL. So you might have a Images.aspx page and route map to your page like this:

```
/images/{imageID}
```

which could translate to `Images.apsx?ImageID={imageID}`. This "page" does not return any html... only the image, with an `image/jpeg` content type. Then the `src` attribute for your html `<img` element in the main page can point to your new route.

No matter what you do, the important thing to understand is you are using HTTP's request/response model. The `<img` element in the page should be supplied via a completely separate HTTP request, and not as part of the same request that provided the html.